The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files error with JasperReport in Netbeans
I use JasperReport Plugin(iReport-5.6.0-plugin) in Netbeans19.I tried to compile .jrxml file but The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files occured.My java platform is jdk 1.8. That is my .jrxml file. Language is java but when I change it to groovy, it works but not useful for deploy to another machine.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="748f881f-3efb-44d0-8d9f-984eda83ed63">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.3" value="lastPageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="true"/>
    <parameter name="baslangicTarihi" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="bitisTarihi" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="idList" class="java.util.List">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select b.ad,s.ad as statu,count(distinct yb.belge_no) as sayi from ETOBS.GTB_ETOBS_O_YENIBELGE yb,ETOBS.GTB_ETOBS_BIRIM b ,ETOBS.GTB_ETOBS_BELGE_STATU s
where YB.BELGE_BIRIM_ID=B.ID and S.ID=YB.STATU_ID and YB.SEVK_SONRASI_ID=3 and YB.GONDERIM_TARIHI between $P{baslangicTarihi} and $P{bitisTarihi}+1 and  $X{IN,yb.belge_birim_id,idList}
group by b.ad,s.ad 
order by b.ad asc]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="AD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="STATU" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SAYI" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="66" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" uuid="3fde9df3-0e91-4c4a-a619-2430dfb6c505"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[İstatistik Raporu]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="285" height="20" uuid="084a0f6d-cdfd-4df6-a3e4-bac4eedd8c13"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Gümrük Müdürlüğü]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="285" y="33" width="112" height="20" uuid="648fcfe5-f901-43c6-b82e-8ac53f9170c3"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Belge Sayısı]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="397" y="33" width="158" height="20" uuid="51d4b54e-146b-4d43-a9cb-80b46be3c1e2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Statüsü]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="44" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="285" height="20" uuid="83582f06-7770-4f7a-ac03-2f56298e5f90"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{AD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="285" y="10" width="112" height="20" uuid="834b28b7-8ab5-498f-87ea-b9fcb41a6566"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SAYI}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="397" y="10" width="158" height="20" uuid="79c77746-5b4d-42a6-8d5e-32fe4a59c18b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATU}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>

